# Superquadric trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm finding some difficulties in solving with respect $\beta \in [-\pi, \pi]$ the following trigonometric equation
\begin{equation*}
\text{sign}(\tan \beta)\,|\tan \beta|^{\varepsilon}= \frac{\eta}{\xi}
\end{equation*}
where $\eta,\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ are given parameters. My solution, that I have found by introducing (via trial and error) a correcting term $\Delta \beta$, is the following
\begin{equation*}
\beta = \text{sign}\left(\frac{\eta}{\xi}\right)\,\left\{
\tan^{-1}\left(\left|\frac{\eta}{\beta}\right|^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}\right)
-\Delta \beta(\xi)\right\}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}\Delta \beta(\xi)\triangleq \begin{cases}
0   & \text{ if } \xi \geq 0 \\
\pi & \text{ otherwise} \\
\end{cases}\end{equation*}

According to my code, it seems to work. To be honest, it is not to clear to me how one can justify $\Delta \beta$.
I would like to know:

1. if my solution is correct
2. how to justify $\Delta \beta$